# PInvoke Passing structure with a nested structure array C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a structure in C# which needs to be passed to a C++ DLL.

```
typedef struct
{
    TDate  fDate;
    double fRate;
} TRatePt;

typedef struct _TCurve2
{
    int       fNumItems;     /* Number of TRatePts in fArray */
    TRatePt  *fArray;        
    TDate     fBaseDate;     
} TCurve2;
```

The following is the structure I've created in C#.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), Serializable]
public struct TRatePt
{
    public int fDate;
    public double fRate;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), Serializable]
public struct TCurve2
{
    public int fNumItems;
    public IntPtr fArray;
    public int fBaseDate;
}
```

I have a simple method in the C DLL.

```
EXPORT int TestMethodForZC(TCurve2 *discCurve)
{
    printf("\n\nIn TestMethodForZC\n");
    printf("discCurve->fBaseDate = %d\n\n\n",discCurve->fBaseDate );
    return 0;
}
```

And I'm using PInvoke to call it using the following:

```
[DllImport("clibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "TestMethodForZC", , CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int _TestMethodForZC(ref TCurve2 discCurve);
```

Marshaling of TRatePt:

```
 TRatePt[] items = new TRatePt[2];
 items[0].fDate = 200;
 items[1].fDate = 300;

 items[0].fRate = 0.2d;
 items[1].fRate = 0.3d;
 TCurve2 tc2 = new TCurve2() { fBaseDate = 12000, fNumItems = 2 };

 tc2.fNumItems = items.Length;
 tc2.fArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(items.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TRatePt)));

 IntPtr item = tc2.fArray;
 for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
 {
     Marshal.StructureToPtr(items[i], item, false);
     item = new IntPtr(item.ToInt32() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TRatePt)));
     }

 _TestMethodForZC(ref tc2);
```

I'm marshaling the TRatePt manually and passing the IntPtr to the method but it is printing junk values. I tried Int32 and Int64 on the Marshaling but it makes no difference. Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions?

PS: I tried looking up for this question in stackoverflow and I found one with quite a bit of discussion but none of the suggestions worked for me.

Comment: I suspect your calling convention is wrong -- try adding `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` to your `DllImport` attribute constructor.

Comment: Where on Earth did TCurve come from?

Comment: @ildjarn I added the CallingConvention but it still does the same.

Comment: @Hans Passant That was a typo and I corrected it.

Comment: What are your build settings and what is your target platform? Maybe there is a hidden 32/64 issue (e.g. one dll is build in 32 bit mode, core is build with any and suddently you run in 32 bit mode on a 64 bit os).

Comment: @weismat Both of them are configured to be 32 bit. I have them both in the same solution too.

Comment: The Code is working now. I have made the changes accordingly to the question for other's reference. Thanks all for your help.